# Git checkout file - casing in file name

Tags: git, git-checkout, casing

Git newbie here :)

Faced casing-related problem: file `aspnetdb.mdf` was removed from repository several commits ago, I decided to restore it from some of earlier commits and did it is such way:

```
git checkout master~3 aspnetdb.mdf
```

*wanted to get file from 3rd back commit*

But git said, that there was no such file.
Then I executed following:

```
git checkout master~3 ASPNETDB.MDF
```

which worked fine - I had got needed file.

HOWEVER. Command `git checkout master~3 aspnetdb_log.ldf` (with low-case file name) command executed fine. During all dev. Process both files were processing in same way (no hack renames etc. :) ).

How explain such behavior? What had I done wrong?

Comment: Are you on Windows (msysgit) and did you set the `core.ignorecase` to true? See for instance http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=Git_Usage#Git_.28OSX.2FWindows.29

Comment: Yap, I'm using Windows. Totally forgot about core.`ignorecase` setting. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, since you are using Git on a case insensitive system (Windows), try and set **`core.ignorecase`** properly. Check with:

```
$ git-config --list
```

If not set:

```
$ git-config --global core.ignorecase true
```